# Google Places API - Which data can i store?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am about to create a application which uses Google Places Api.

As long as i understand the terms it is not allowed to store places data in my database
like name, latitude, longitude or detail informations. Is that right ?

I found that it is allowed to "cache" the data instead of storing it.

In order to show the "last used places" on my website i need to store something (e.g. the reference id of the place).

Which informations about a place can i store in my database ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can only store the Place ID in your database. Everything else has to be requested each time you want to display the data.

Comment: What good is the place id to store, if it has no context? If the user called some phone number from the result and saw its name, is it ok to store a mapping between the phone number he called, and the place-id, together with the name of the place?

Answer (score 0):

You can store place_id from google places response. If you want to make some actions with that data, you can store place_id in your local table along user_id. for example if you want to like any restaurant from google response:

```
user_id: 1,
place_id: "xyz",
isLiked: true
```

You can design like above in local database. And you can take "place_id" from this table and fetch full restaurant data from google places api.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand you can store everything from the APi:
`(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.`
But you cannot store the users data, unless consented: 
`(i) Your Maps API Implementation must notify the user in advance of the type(s) of data that you intend to collect from the user or the user's device. Your Maps API Implementation must not obtain or cache any user's location in any manner except with the user's prior consent. Your Maps API Implementation must let the user revoke the user's consent at any time.`

Refereced from [google places terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) (yes it is the same as the google maps)

See these two links:

- https://developers.google.com/places/policies#pre-fetching_caching_or_storage_of_content
- https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3

Comment: Weird how you came to that conclusion as the first sentence says No pre-fetching, caching, or storage of content. The only thing you can store is the place ID.